# How to use a listview of UI thread in DoWork event handler?

Tags: .net, listviewitem

I have listview on the UI thread. I have some operations to be performed through the background worker's DoWork event handler since they are time consuming. But I cant acess the listview items in my DoWork handler since it raises an exception:`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'bufferedListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

So how do I acess my bufferedlistview in my DoWork event handler.
This is the code to be handled in DoWork:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in bufferedListView1.Items) 
{ 
    string lname = bufferedListView1.Items[i].Text; 
    string lno = bufferedListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text; 
    string gname = bufferedListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text; 
    string line = lname + "@" + lno + "@" + gname; 
    if (gname.Contains(sgroup)) 
    { 
        var m = Regex.Match(line, @"([\w]+)@([+\d]+)@([\w]+)"); 
        if (m.Success) 
        { 
            port.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + m.Groups[2].Value + "\""); 
            port.Write(txt_msgbox.Text + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26)); 
            Thread.Sleep(4000); 
        } 
        sno++; 
    } 
    i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I wanted was to **read the listview in UI thread in other thread**. All the solutions given were using `invoke` method but I found a rather easy way to do this:

```
ListView lvItems = new ListView(); \\in global scope
```

At the required location in my code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in bufferedListView1.Items)
{
   lvItems.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone()); // Copied the bufferedListview's items that are to be accessed in other thread to another listview- listItems
}
```

Then used the `lvItems` listview in my `DoWork` event handler. Simple n Easy :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.perceler.com/articles1.php?art=crossthreads1) a good article on the topic of cross-threaded access to controls in winforms.

Basically, whenever you access controls not from the UI thread, you have to use

```
control.Invoke
```

construct.

Comment: So does that mean that if I use Somecontrol.Invoke(), and something like what @Hassan showed, I can access directly the bufferedListView items in DoWork?

Comment: This is what I tried. Is it correct in my case? `delegate ListView itemDelegate(ListView bufferedListView1);

       private ListView getItems(ListView bufferedListView1)  
       {  
           if (bufferedListView1.InvokeRequired)  
           {  
               BeginInvoke(new itemDelegate(getItems));  
           }  
           else  
           {  
               return bufferedListView1;  
           }  
       }`

Answer (score 0):

the mistake come from the fact that you try to access to UIThread from another thread (backgrounworker thread) to get a UI control

use  InvokeRequired
you have to implement a delegate 
here a sample

```
 delegate void valueDelegate(string value);

    private void SetValue(string value)
    {
       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
           BeginInvoke(new valueDelegate(SetValue),value);
       }
       else
       {
           someControl.Text = value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: So does that mean that if I use Somecontrol.Invoke(), and something like what you showed, I can access directly the bufferedListView items in DoWork?